# How to Export Gensim Word2Vec Model with Ngram Weights for DL4J?

Tags: java, nlp, gensim, word2vec, deeplearning4j

I'm quite new to nlp. I'm trying to use a model trained with gensim in dl4j. I'm saving the model with

```
w2v_model.wv.save_word2vec_format("path/to/w2v_model.bin", binary=True)
```

and afterwards I'm loading it with

```
Word2Vec w2vModel = WordVectorSerializer.readWord2VecModel("path/to/w2v_model.bin");
```

The model works well except for the handling of out-of-vocabulary (OOV) words. In Gensim, it seems to calculate vectors for OOV words based on the word's n-grams, but in DL4J, it provides an empty vector for them.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to export the n-gram weights along with the model from Gensim so that DL4J can use them?
2. If exporting the n-gram weights is not possible, is there a method to reconstruct them on the DL4J side to achieve similar results for OOV words as in Gensim?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The core original word2vec algorithm – and the `Word2Vec` model class in Gensim – has no ability to synthesize vectors for OOV words using character n-grams.

That's only a feature of FastText models (and the `FastText` model class in Gensim) – so if you're seeing that working in Gensim, your `w2v_model` variable may actually hold a Gensim `FastText` object.

Further, the plain {word, vector}-per-line format saved by Gensim's `.save_word2vec_format()` (whether `binary=False` or `binary=True`) doesn't save any subword n-grams, even if used on a `FastText` object. (It just saves the full-word vectors for in-vocabulary words.)

Gensim's `FastText` can save models in the full raw model format also used by Facebook's original FastText implementation – see [`FastText.save_facebook_model()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.save_facebook_model).

But to bring that to a Java environment, you'd need to find a true FastText implementation that also reads that format. I don't see any evidence that the `Word2Vec` class in DL4J supports FastText features or load FastText models.

There *is* an [`org.deeplearning4j.models.fasttext.FastText`](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp-parent/deeplearning4j-nlp/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/models/fasttext/FastText.java) class – which seems to wrap the Facebook native C++ FastText implementation via another `com.github.jfasttext.JFastText`. That is, it's not a true Java implementation, but it makes the model accessible to Java code.

I have no idea of the completeness/reliability of this approach; it's a little fishy to me that a class (`JFastText`) not from a Github engineer is named via a `com.github` path, but presumably the `deeplearning4j` maintainers know what they're doing, and this may be your best option for loading a fully-capable (character-n-gram features) FastText model for use in DL4J.